# What is the true way to create a child window in MFC?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have created the project for SDI MFC application with document/view architecture.

Now, I want to separate my main window and the Board(I trying to write a board game). I want to put the board to child window, for further lightweight abitlity to center them depend on the size of parent(main) window.

And actually I already did that, but now I have a problenm - I also want to wait messages from the mouse.

```
class CGameView {
  // ...
  CGameView()
  {
    childWnd = new CWnd;
  }

  ~CGameView()
  {
    delete childWnd;
  }

  void CGameView::OnSize(UINT nType, int cx, int cy) {
    CGameDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if(!pDoc)
      return;
    // I bind the height of child window with height of parent
    RECT rcClient;
    GetClientRect(&rcClient);
    rcClient.left = 0;
    rcClient.right = pDoc->getWidth();
    childWnd->MoveWindow(&rcClient);

    childWnd->CenterWindow();

    return;
  }

  int CGameView::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)
  {
    if (CView::OnCreate(lpCreateStruct) == -1)
      return -1;

    CGameDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();
    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if(!pDoc)
      return -1;

    childWnd->Create(NULL, NULL, WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE,
       CRect(0, 0, pDoc->getWidth(), pDoc->getHeight()), this, 0);

    return 0;
  }

  void CGameView::OnDraw(CDC* pDC)
  {
    CGameDoc* pDoc = GetDocument();

    ASSERT_VALID(pDoc);
    if (!pDoc)
        return;

    CRect rcClient;
    GetClientRect(&rcClient);
    CClientDC cdc(childWnd);
  // The pOffScreen contains the bitmap that I just copy to specified CDC
    pOffScreen->print(&cdc, &rcClient);

  }
}
```

? I am strongly care about correctness of the way that I did my child window.
? Now, I don't know that how to beautyfully listen the mouse messages by my child window ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generally speaking, you should not create objects of type `CWnd` directly.

Instead, create a sublcass of `CWnd` and create an object of that type. Then you can manage the mouse, paint and any other events with member functions of that class.

```
class CBoardWnd : public CWnd
{
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
    //...
};
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CBoardWnd, CWnd)
    ON_WM_MOUSEMOVE(...)
    //...
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

Comment: So, all what I wrote will be remain except using CBoardWnd instead `new CWnd;` right ? and it is correct to make window in the `view class` ?

Comment: @RaimbekRakhimbek: Yes, you can build any child windows of the `CWnd` as you want. They can even subclass `CView` and use the `UpdateDocument()` mechanism (you have have many views per document), but I usually don't bother too much with those...

Comment: Oh, I have a stick again : How to pass the information about message to document ?

Comment: @RaimbekRakhimbek: I'd do `childWnd = new CBoardWnd(pDoc);` just before the call to `CWnd::Create()`. And in your class you save the pointer to the document and use it at will.